# Eclipse (Mule ESB) Error: java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mule, esb

From Eclipse I added a database connection using JDBC.  To do this I did the following

I created a User Library, as follows

> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path => User Libraries
>
> Then press the 'New' button, and create a lib
>
> Then hit the 'Add External JARs' button to add JARS external to ECLIPSE

From there I loaded the following files:

```
db2jcc.jar
db2jcc_license_cu.jar
```

Then I added the User Library I created to the project Build path as follows:

- Rt click on the project
- click on Properties
- Click on "Java Build Path"
- Check "TEST_LIB" (the name of the User Library

Then I selected the Driver name class from the wizard (now that the libraries are in the project, magically the GUI can see the class name

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

I select the class name and put in a url, and TEST THE CONNECTION

The test of the connection is SUCCESSFUL  !!!!

I am happy so I pop in a prepared statement:

```
SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM ACCOUNT
```

And then I run the flow as a "Mule Application"

But when I sent an http message to it I  get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver :
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver (org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.Connect
ionCreationException). Message payload is of type: String
```

So I can now test the connection when the flow is not running, but when the flow is running, it can not find the driver I used to test the connection with

Any ideas of where I should look to resolve this issue

Comment: I think you need to add jars in server runtime. copy jars at MuleStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201304102100\mule\opt location. Restart MuleStudio/Eclipse and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STUDIO packages your app and deploys this in Mule server, in doing this it is not packaging the jars you are adding via user libraries. A workaround is to ass the jars via "Add external jars" in "Java Build Path" of the project